# How to declare local var global

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am reading data in from a grid and for the life of me, cannot seem to find a way to make a local var global work. I got some help here recently and still seem to be having problems. I have posted a small portion of the code for your reference and would be grateful if someone could ncheck it and tell me where I am going wrong? I have declared var titleitem = ''; outside of the function and need to find a way to create a global var using var = act_item portion of the code. I thought that ommiting the var, this became a global var and could be used outside of the function. In this case var titleitem. This would then be used in dialog as part of the title. $('#actionform').dialog({title : titleitem});

All that is returned in console.log is (an empty string).

Thanks

```
<!--- function to action data -->
<script type="text/javascript">

                var titleitem = '';

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function action(com,grid) {


        if(com == 'Action') {
                if( $('.trSelected').length>0 ) {
            var items = $('.trSelected');
                        var itemlist ='';
                        for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                            itemlist+= items[i].id.substr(3);
                        }
                var act_id = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(1) div").text();
                var act_location = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(2) div").text();
                var act_service = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(3) div").text();
                var act_activity = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(4) div").text();
                var act_department = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(5) div").text();
                var act_company = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(6) div").text();
                var act_address = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(7) div").text();
                var act_user = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(8) div").text();
                act_item = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(9) div").text();
                $titleitem = act_item;
```

+++++UPDATE++++++

```
$("#actionform").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            title: "Input new intake"+titleitem,
            width: 470,
            beforeclose: function (event, ui) {
                if(flag==1){
                    flag=0;
                    jAlert("You have successfully actioned\n\rBox: "+act_item+"\n\r",
                                                     'New Intake successfull');

                }

                $("#ACT_message").html("");
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $("#ACT_action").get(0).reset();
                $("#ACT_message").html("");

            }

        });
```

Comment: You probably want `titleitem = act_item;` (without the `$`). There is no need to make `act_item` global.

Comment: @felix please see my answer to patrick. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this...

```
act_item = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(9) div").text();
```

...will be global, but I think it is better to make it explicitly global by declaring it *outside* your function...

```
var act_item;
function action(com,grid) {
    ...
}
```

...or by explicitly making it a property of `window`...

```
function action(com,grid) {
    ...
    window.act_item = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(9) div").text();
}
```

Although there is often a better solution than to pollute the global namespace.

Also, be aware that this...

```
$titleitem = act_item;
```

...is a different variable name from your initial one because it starts with a `$`.

If your globals are not working, make sure they're declared/initialized *before* you're trying to use them.

*(Your code doesn't show where you're doing `$('#actionform').dialog({title : titleitem});`.)*

Comment: I am now using act_item = $("tr.trSelected td:nth-child(9) div").text();
titleitem = act_item; and outside of the function I have this: <script type="text/javascript">

 var titleitem = '';
 var act_item;
</script> also the value is appearing in console but not being displayed in the dialog title. Thanks

Comment: @bollo: I see your updated code, but you still have `$titleitem` instead of `titleitem` in your `action()` function. Also we still can't tell *where* the `.dialog()` is located in relation to the rest of your code. This is fairly important.

Comment: That was the original code. The new code starts under the update text. I have put all the code @ http://jsfiddle.net/ydJPV/ I hope I can get this sorted as it is quite important. Thanks

Comment: @bollo: It appears as though you're never invoking your `action(com, grid)` function, so the values are never being set.

Comment: the function is being invoked like this: {name: 'Action', bclass: 'action', onpress : action}, Thanks

Comment: @bollo: Is that server side code? If so, what does it translate to? A click event? If so, keep in mind that your `$("#actionform").dialog({` runs when the `document` loads, which will be before any click in the document has a chance to occur.

Comment: Patrick.I am using flexigrid and this is how I call functions from buttons. In fact, it is probably the only way. It is js. Thanks

Comment: @bollo: So if I understand you correctly, it requires a click on a button to invoke the `action()` function. Is that right? If so, then you'd need to trigger a click event when the page loads. I don't know anything about `flexigrid`, but try triggering a `.click()` on one of the buttons when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Patrick. yes. How would I do that. Here is the code in the flexigrid that calls the functions. buttons : [
{name: 'Action', bclass: 'action', onpress : action},
{separator: true},
{name: 'Delete', bclass: 'delete', onpress : test},
{separator: true},
{name: 'Edit', bclass: 'edit', onpress : editact},
{separator: true},
{name: 'Help', bclass: 'help', onpress : help},
{separator: true}
], Thanks

Comment: If the buttons have the class `"action"` on them, then just do `$('.action').triggerHandler( 'click' );` *after* the `flexigrid` code has run.

Comment: patrick. is bclass considered the correct class name. The function of that here, is that it loads the image for the button.

Comment: patrick. I have placed that where I think the dom finishes loading but still no difference. Is there a way to check when the dom has loaded. Thanks

Comment: The code you placed inside of `$(function() { ... });` executes after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the variable "titleitem" and not "$titleitem" in your "action" function.